# Read .ini and convert string into DateTime powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, datetime, scripting

Ok, Basically i'm doing a read/write to a .ini config file here.  What I'm pulling from the .ini is a string in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt`.  The part I cant seem to incorporate is the 'tt' portion (AM/PM).  Any time I try to execute this code:

```
$ConvertStringToDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($value,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "ParseExact" and the argument count: "3".
At line:1 char:1
+ $ConvertStringToDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($value,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:m ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I'm very certain that I have the:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Wrong.  I've tried tons of variations of how to fix this and cant seem to figure it out.

```
function Get-IniContent ($FilePathINI)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePathINI
    {
        “^\[(.+)\]” # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        “^(;.*)$” # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = “Comment” + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        } 
        “(.+?)\s*=(.*)” # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}
function Out-IniFile($InputObject, $FilePathINI)
{
    $outFile = New-Item -ItemType file -Path $FilePathINI -Force
    foreach ($i in $InputObject.keys)
    {
        if (!($($InputObject[$i].GetType().Name) -eq “Hashtable”))
        {
            #No Sections
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value “$i=$($InputObject[$i])”
        } else {
            #Sections
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value “[$i]”
            Foreach ($j in ($InputObject[$i].keys | Sort-Object))
            {
                if ($j -match “^Comment[\d]+”) {
                    Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value “$($InputObject[$i][$j])”
                } else {
                    Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value “$j=$($InputObject[$i][$j])” 
                }

            }
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value “”
        }
    }
}



$store = @()

Foreach($event in Get-EventLog "Application" -Newest 50 | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 18456})
{
   #$EventID = $event.EventID
   $store += $Event
}

$sortedEvents = $store | Sort-Object -Descending

$latestEvent = $sortedEvents[0]

$eventDate = $latestEvent.TimeGenerated
$culture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
#$eventDate = (get-date).Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")



$iniContent = Get-IniContent "C:\Scripts\EventLog\EventConfig.ini"
$value = $iniContent["section"]["LastProcessDate"]


$ConvertStringToDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($value,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)
```

Comment: Can you just give us an example of a date within your ini that you want to pass. Also, what PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: I pull a string from the .ini file in this format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt

so  I.E. 01/01/2017 12:01:02 PM

Comment: v1.0 on powershell i believe or whatever comes with win 10

Comment: @Keifer - You can add the output from `$PSVersionTable` to get all version info we need.

Comment: It was the 'HH' in the format. it needed to be 'hh' that fixed everything.